# Staking Key a Privacy risk?

Tags: address, privacy

So I just realized today that the staking key for a wallet is persistent, namely that every public key of that wallet will generate the same staking key. This appears to undercut the technique to use different public keys every transaction, since they can be verified to be connected through their staking key. Can staking keys be generated on the curve like public addresses are to preserve privacy?

Answer (score 6):

> Can staking keys be generated on the curve like public addresses are
> to preserve privacy?

While it is possible to create [enterprise addresses](https://docs.cardano.org/en/latest/learn/types-addresses.html#enterprise-addresses) or additional [base addresses](https://docs.cardano.org/en/latest/learn/types-addresses.html#base-addresses) with new staking keys using [cardano-cli](https://docs.cardano.org/projects/cardano-node/en/latest/getting-started/cli.html), the official wallets at present will re-use the same staking key for all addresses of the same wallet if you choose to stake.

Instructions on how you can create [enterprise addresses](https://docs.cardano.org/en/latest/learn/types-addresses.html#enterprise-addresses) or [base addresses](https://docs.cardano.org/en/latest/learn/types-addresses.html#base-addresses) with different staking keys can be found on the [Lovelace Academy documentation on the basics of keys and addresses](https://learn.lovelace.academy/getting-started/keys-and-addresses/).

*Note: Using multiple staking keys to stake will incur a deposit fee of 2 ADA each (at time of writing)*

Comment: The staking key is part of the address, so creating a new wallet and not staking it will not help. You can use enterprise addresses via CLI ehich have no staking key or you should be able to use old Byron type addresses.

Comment: You're right @Xiaofei, I assumed incorrectly that the wallets did not append staking keys unless the users chose to stake but it does make sense all existing ADA should be staked. Removing option a)! :)